# Porque este erro de sintaxe SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$termos = (explode('/', implode('/', $_GET['tipo'])));
print_r($termos);

Array
(
    [0] => CASA
    [1] => CASA EM CONDOMINIO
    [2] => COBERTURA
)
```

Estou com um erro de sintaxe nessa SQL que faz loops para adicionar quantos termos forem necessários que são capturados dentro `array` acima:

```
$sql = array('0');
foreach($termos as $termo){
    $sql[] = 'CATEGORIA LIKE %'.$termo.'%';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE ' .implode(' OR ', $sql);
```

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Não consigo descobrir qual o erro de sintaxe alertado.

Comment: Não esqueceu de colocar aspas simples no termo do `LIKE`? Como: `CATEGORIA LIKE '%CASA%'`.

Comment: Ecoe essa string SQL. Esse `array(0)`, por exemplo, não estaria produzindo algo como `WHERE 0 OR CATEGORIA LIKE...`?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, esse `WHERE 0 OR ...` funciona. Segue um SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c439/3

Comment: O link não abriu como esperado.

Comment: Eita, saiu do ar... Quando voltar dará pra ver o funcionamento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu script está gerando um SQL com a cláusula `LIKE` sem as aspas simples.

Algo como:

```
SELECT *
FROM imovel
WHERE 0
OR CATEGORIA LIKE %CASA%
OR CATEGORIA LIKE %CASA EM CONDOMINIO%
OR CATEGORIA LIKE %COBERTURA%
```

O que não é válido segundo a documentação do operador [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) do [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

A solução é incluir as aspas na construção do seu `Array`, como:

```
foreach($termos as $termo){
    $sql[] = 'CATEGORIA LIKE \'%'.$termo.'%\'';
}

//ou

foreach($termos as $termo){
    $sql[] = "CATEGORIA LIKE '%".$termo."%'";
}
```

Comment: Percebi que para incluir as aspas, é preciso dar barra invertida, bom saber disso, acabei conseguindo de outro jeito mas a sua aplicação é correta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui acertar o erro de sintaxe e o código ficou assim:

```
$sql = array('0');
foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = "CATEGORIA LIKE '%{$word}%'";
}

$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE ' .implode(' OR ', $sql);
$sql   .= ' ORDER BY IMO_CODIGO DESC LIMIT '.$inicio. ', '. $limite;
```

Com este código é possível recuperar termos de `arrays`, seja quantos forem e fazer uma consulta de um por um para ter o retorno do banco de dados. Exemplo:

> Cores da fachada:

```
Array
(
    [0] => VERDE
    [1] => VERMELHO
    [2] => AZUL
    [3] => AMARELO
    [4] => BRANCO
    [5] => PRETO
    [6] => CINZA
)
```

Caso este `array` seja resultado de uma `checkbox` por exemplo, essa instrução retorna as fachadas com as cores selecionadas.

Obrigado SOpt.